# How to get cell value when that cell is clicked?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

When user clicks a table cell Vue should be aware of its value. In this case I am trying to set an event and pass the value.

Is there any way I could write this better, maybe from Vue itself - for example when the cell is clicked first get its content? I have many cells in table, and  this doesn't work, it works only if I remove PHP part and try to write it manually - `@click="calculate_price(10)`

```
<?php foreach ($tr as $td) : ?>
    <td @click="calculate_price(<?php echo $td['price']; ?>)">
        <?php echo $td['price']; ?>
    </td>
<?php endforeach; ?>


var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        price: 0
    },
    methods: {
        calculate_price: function (price) {
            console.log(price);
        }
    }
})
```

Vue version is 2.4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind the click event to the `<table>` and get the deepest element from the `event` to see which `<td>` was clicked and what value is in there.

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/at0sdhsh/